# PHP Insert Statement running twice in Firefox, once in I.E

Tags: php, mysql, firefox

I'm truly stuck here.  I have an insert statement that runs twice on Firefox, but (correctly) only once in I.E.

What could be causing Firefox to run the insert statement twice?  It only runs this query twice, not the others on the page.  I went as far as to comment out ALL other code except for what I'm posting below and it still inserts twice in Firefox.

```
if((isset($_GET['stepNum']))&&(isset($_GET['idNum']))){
    $stepNum = $_GET['stepNum'];
    $idNum = $_GET['idNum'];

    $startCycleNum = 1;
    $startCycleStatus = 1;
    $cycleGo = true;
    }//end isset if statement
try {
    if ($cycleGo == true) {
$stmtC = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable (cycleNum, cycleStatus, processID) VALUES (:cycleNum, :cycleStatus, :processID)');
$stmtC->execute(array(':cycleNum' => $startCycleNum, ':cycleStatus' => $startCycleStatus, ':processID' => $idNum));
$cycleGo = false; 
$newCycle = $db->lastInsertId();

    }
}//end try
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo '<h5>There was an error saving the new cycle.  Please try again.</h5>';
}//end catch
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  I tried clearing my cache in Firefox to no avail.

EDIT: Code from submitting form getsteps.php

```
if ($stepNum != 'none') {
    echo '<form name="addNewForm" action="createcycleone?idNum='.$idNum.'stepNum='.$stepNum.'" method="post">

    <table width = "100%" id="formfields">';

    //form inputs

echo '<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" value="Save and Create Cycle"></input></td></tr>
</table>
</form> ';
}
```

EDIT: Code from the php page calling getSteps.php to load the correct number of steps (fields)

```
//get the stepNum
if((isset($_GET['nid']))&&(isset($_GET['idNum']))){
$stepNum = $_GET['nid'];
$idNum = $_GET['idNum'];
}
  <form id="stepsForm" name="stepsForm">
      <table width ="100%" id="stepfield">

        <tr><td><strong>Number of Steps:</strong></td>
        <td><select name="getSteps" id="getSteps" onchange="$('#formContainer1').load('../files/createUAT/getSteps.php?nid='+this.value+'&idNum='+<?php print $idNum; ?>);">
        <option value="none">Select a Number</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
</td></tr></table>
</form>


<div id ="formContainer1" class="formContainer1">

</div>
```

Comment: I did not carefully study your code, but unless there's some JS involved, I can't see how the browser could possibly make any difference.

Comment: Who downvotes this immediately?  It's not like I haven't tried searching for this before posting...

Comment: Are there any loops involved I see $cycleGo = false; and wonder is there is something else outside this code. Does the PDOExecption ever fire off?

Comment: Yes, the issue is most likely in how the page itself is being submitted (either via Javascript, or some other means).  Most likely, it's being submitted via AJAX and then afterwards the Submit button event is firing as well (which can work differently in different browsers, depending on how it's constructed).

Comment: Since it’s server-side code (and nothing in it handles anything browser-specific), your question can not be answered with that – so what’s the corresponding HTML/JavaScript that triggers this script being run in the first place? Maybe any external resources (scripts, images, etc.) embedded in the HTML document with an empty src/href attribute? (Those are a common cause of “inexplicable” double requests.) Anything in the net panel of Firebug that suggests there are two requests for the script being made?

Comment: All I have loaded is jQuery, which I have loaded on pretty much every page without issues.  Firebug only shows one call.

Comment: @Jacob, I have the page being loaded from a form that is within an jQuery AJAX call.  Think that's the issue?

Comment: @SimonBennett - there are no loops in this page at all and no exceptions.

Comment: @wiscWeb perhaps, but would need to see the page code to know more, as CBroe said.

Comment: Added everything in my OP that could possibly be the issue.  It still inserts twice on Firefox even with jQuery disabled.  I'm literally running nothing but the first block of code on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is causing the issue, but change this...

```
'idNum='+<?php print $idNum; ?>
```

...to this..

```
'&idNum=<?php print $idNum; ?>'
```

That might be causing some cross-browser differences.

Comment: Tried...  Unfortunately I'm still getting 2 new rows on Firefox.

Comment: How will such basic concatenation in javascript give cross browser issues ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer when submitting an integer that works, but when the value "none" comes through from the first option, most browsers will throw a JS error (as they should), but I've seen some (ahem*IE*ahem) try to auto-correct such errors.  Not what's causing this issue, but worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you turn off error reporting in your php script and see if the problem persists.`error_reporting(0);` I had the same problem with firefox and that worked. Otherwise, check out [Similar question and suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016784/pages-load-twice-on-firefox/37876441#37876441)

Answer (score 0):

If you output **any** text before the `<HTML>` tag, **firefox** has the bad habit to **reload** the page. That means, your code will executed twice.

I suggest to make sure that any output (queries results, debugging messages etc...) is properly inside the `<body>` html tag and not outside of it.

That thing drove me crazy once, while i was outputing the query to the very beginning of the markup (for debugging).

If that is the case i will be surprised this nasty behaviour still exists.

edit: oh, i just saw this question is from 2013... xD. Somehow stackoverflow popped this up and i thought it was a recent question.

Well anyway this probably is your answer folks!